Host not found in upstream - AWS ECS and Docker
I’m trying to update my ECS (Elastic Container Service) task definition. I am changing my SendGrid API Key for my backend service.
So I am deploying this updated task definition by updating the ECS, and it triggers a deployment of the containers.
During the redeployment, nginx, which is probably a proxy of the docker container service is encountering an error. The error is that nginx is unable to resolve the uwsgi service. I checked whether nginx is able to ping and wget uwsgi.   So I’m pretty much scratching my head because this is supposed to happen without much issue, but I’m left unable to resolve it.
This is the error:
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backendUwsgi" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/backend.conf:45

Is there a way I can do this ideally without pushing anything onto Github and making some changes on the AWS console? What kind of changes might I have to make?
The nginx conf file:
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

server {

  listen  80 default_server;
  server_name ${HOST};
  charset     utf-8;

  client_max_body_size 500m;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_types text/plain
             text/css
             application/json
             application/x-javascript
             text/xml
             application/xml
             application/xml+rss
             text/javascript
             application/javascript
             application/x-font-opentype
             image/svg+xml;
  gzip_comp_level 9;
  gzip_vary on;

  location = /api/v1/***** {
    return 200;
    access_log off;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    client_body_timeout 600;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 600;

    proxy_set_header Host ${HOST};
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass  http://${UWSGI_APP}:${UWSGI_PORT};
  }
}

Should I just add this line called "upstream" in the nginx conf and redeploy? Not sure. The "backendUwsgi" is mentioned in the properties and listening on port 9000

Do try add resolver 127.0.0.11 on nginx.conf file. Check that values on ${} its working.
